# Rails Paperclip Gem Saving Multiple Attachments per Model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to Rails development and having a problem saving multiple images/attachments to a model.  My problem is that the code below is not actually saving to the item_images table when I submit the form.  I am following [This Article](https://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/) as a guide, though it seems to be a bit out of date.  I feel I'm in a little over my head at this point so I hope someone can point out what I'm missing.  Thanks!

I have the following models:

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_images, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['item_image'].nil? }
end
```

**item_image.rb**

```
class ItemImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    has_attached_file :image,
                      :styles => { thumb: "100x100#", small: "400x400#", large: "700x700" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

My controller looks like this:

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = Item.new
    4.times {@item.item_images.build}
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
    4.times {@item.item_images.build}
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :price, :available, :sort_shop, :sort_gallery, :item_type, :size)
    end
end
```

**form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @item, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :available %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :available %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sort_shop %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :sort_shop %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sort_gallery %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :sort_gallery %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :item_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :size %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :size %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :item_images do |builder| %>

    <% if builder.object.new_record? %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= builder.label :image, "Image File" %>
    <%= builder.file_field :image %>
    </div>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you need to permit `item_images_attributes` also in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in strong parameters in Items controller

`params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :price, :available, :sort_shop, :sort_gallery, :item_type, :size,item_images_attributes: [:image ])`

than in ItemImage.rb add this line 
`belongs_to :item, optional: true`,

and remove this line from Item.rb

:reject_if => lambda { |t| t['item_image'].nil? }
 `
If you get any error please reply